# how can prove that the diophantine equation has at most three solutions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, p-adic-number-theory

I am reading an article by F beukers of recurrence sequence, and I have not been able to justify this statement that says it is trivial. If someone can help me or give me a clue or a book to consult on the subject, I would greatly appreciate it.
Consider the equation $$ u_n=\alpha_{1}\theta_{1}^{n}+\alpha_{2}\theta_{2}^{n}+\alpha_{3}\theta_{3}^{n}=0, n\in \mathbb{Z} $$ where $\theta_1, \theta_2, \theta_3 $ are roots of $X^3-PX^2-QX-R$. And suppose that not all are real, and no one of ratios $\frac{\theta_i}{\theta_j} (i \neq j)$ are distinct of zero.

Consider the finite valuations of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3)$. If there exist a valuation $\boldsymbol{v}$ such that $|\theta_1|_{\boldsymbol{v}},|\theta_2|_{\boldsymbol{v}},|\theta_3|_{\boldsymbol{v}}$ are all distinct, then it is easy to see that this equation has at most three solutions.
Thanks...

Comment: perhaps this: http://www.numdam.org/article/CM_1991__77_2_165_0.pdf

Answer (score 2):

If the three $|\alpha_j\theta_j^n|_v$ are all distinct, then
$\sum_j\alpha_j\theta_j^n$ must be nonzero. This is a basic property
of non-Archimedean valuations.

But $|\alpha_1\theta_1^n|_v=|\alpha_2\theta_2^n|_v$
implies $|\alpha_1|_v|\theta_1|^n_v=|\alpha_2|_v|\theta_2|_v^n$,
and as $|\theta_1|_v\ne|\theta_2|_v$ then there is at most one $n$
for which $|\alpha_1\theta_1^n|_v=|\alpha_2\theta_2^n|_v$.
Likewise there is at most one $n$
for which $|\alpha_1\theta_1^n|_v=|\alpha_3\theta_3^n|_v$
and one $n$
for which $|\alpha_2\theta_2^n|_v=|\alpha_3\theta_3^n|_v$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I understand your argument very well, but I do not see how it allows me to conclude that the equation has the most 3 solutions. Excuse me, but I can deduce it.